# Looking for equivalent to UIElement.RenderTransform to visualize level of deviation in Android

Tags: android, animation, graphics, xamarin

We are currently building an app with Xamarin in which we want to visualize the level of deviation from a neutral value. The current state will be updated every 80 to 150 milliseconds.

Basically we're looking for something like this:

---- ´´´´´ ---- (deviation to positive)

---- ----- ---- (no deviation)

---- ___ ---- (deviation to negative)

The lines on the outsides are going to remain in the same position while the line in the middle is moving up and down to show the current deviation.

For WP it is as easy as drawing 3 thin Rectangles in a line and translating values on a Y-Axis to the middle Rectangle via Rectangle.RenderTransform.

In Android we use LevelListDrawable to tie several png's to a certain value range and set the current level from code:
This is the LevelList.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/down"
      android:minLevel="0"
      android:maxLevel="33" />
  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/neutral"
      android:minLevel="34"
      android:maxLevel="66" />
  <item
      android:drawable="@drawable/top"
      android:minLevel="67"
      android:maxLevel="100" />
</level-list>
```

down, neutral and top refer to a .png showing the current state. (There are going to be about 20 different states)

LevelList.xml is set as ImageDrawable for the ImageView which is used to display the current state:

```
_graphicsView = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.GraphicsView);
var drawable = Resources.GetDrawable(Resource.Drawable.LevelList);
_graphicsView.SetImageDrawable(drawable);
```

This is the update method in the MainActivity:

```
public void UpdateDeviation(int deviation)
{
    _graphicsView.SetImageLevel(deviation);
}
```

Our current approach is working but we're not happy about having to store a multitude of png's for every state. Can you think of an better solution for Android with regard to update speed and APK size?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely improve this by implementing your own [SurfaceView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/SurfaceView.html) and rendering a path based the different state.

I was bored so I wrote an example:

**Code:**

```
public enum LineState
{
    Up, Middle, Down,
}

public class OscillatingSurface : SurfaceView
{
    public LineState _state = LineState.Middle;
    private readonly Paint _paint;

    public OscillatingSurface (Context context)
        : base(context) 
    {
        _paint = new Paint(PaintFlags.AntiAlias);
        _paint.SetStyle (Paint.Style.Stroke);
        _paint.Color = Color.White;
        _paint.StrokeWidth = 10.0f;
    }

    public void SetState(LineState state)
    {
        this._state = state;

        float factor = 0.5f;
        if (_state == LineState.Up) {
            factor = 0.6f;
        } else if (state == LineState.Down) {
            factor = 0.4f;
        }

        float width = (float)this.Width;
        float height = (float)this.Height;

        Path path = new Path();

        path.MoveTo (0.0f, height * 0.5f); // Far left point.
        path.LineTo (width * 0.25f, height * 0.5f); // Middle left point.
        path.LineTo (width * 0.25f, height * factor); // Left Oscilation point
        path.LineTo (width * 0.75f, height * factor); // Right oscilation point
        path.LineTo (width * 0.75f, height * 0.5f); // Middle right point.
        path.LineTo (width, height * 0.5f); // Far right point.

        var canvas = this.Holder.LockCanvas (); // Acquire surface.

        canvas.DrawColor (Color.Black); // Clear surface.
        canvas.DrawPath (path, _paint); // Render the path.

        Holder.UnlockCanvasAndPost (canvas); // Release and render!
    }
}

[Activity (Label = "Oscillating Surface", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon")]
public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    OscillatingSurface surface;
    Oscillator oscillator;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        surface = new OscillatingSurface (this);
        oscillator = new Oscillator (this, surface, 1000);
        SetContentView (surface);
    }

    protected override void OnResume ()
    {
        oscillator.Start ();
        base.OnResume ();
    }
}

public class Oscillator
{
    int _frequency;
    OscillatingSurface _surface;
    Activity _owner;

    public Oscillator(Activity owner, OscillatingSurface surface, int frequency)
    {
        _surface = surface;
        _frequency = frequency;
        _owner = owner;
    }

    public void Start()
    {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Run (() => {
            while (true) {
                LineState next = (LineState)((((int)_surface._state) + 1) % 3);
                _owner.RunOnUiThread( () => {
                    _surface.SetState(next);
                });

                Thread.Sleep(_frequency);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**What it does:**

[image] [image] [image]

You only really need to pay attention to the `OscillatingSurface` class in the above code; everything else is just for example.

Resources:

- [Drawable Surface Tutorial](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/707993-how-to-draw-2d-object-in-android-with-a-canvas)
- [Xamarin.Android Drawing Samples](http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/drawing/)

Comment: Very nice solution. Thanks a lot for the extensive answer!